# Position one point per week Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

Bonjour,

I have a data set coming in from my api.
It's coming in this form:

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
        0: {products_id: 793781, products_date_added: "2020-05-05T00:00:00+02:00"}
        1: {products_id: 794543, products_date_added: "2020-02-22T00:00:00+01:00"}
```

And I think that's how I'm supposed to get the dates back?

```
 data = [{
    data: [ [ 5 , 2 ] , [ 6 , 3 ] , [ 8 , 2 ]]
  }];
```

My data are products recovered 3 months ago.
I would like to have on my X-axis total assets over the last 3 months with one point per week. For example for today's date, I would like to have "May" "June" "July".
And on my Y-axis I'd like to get the total good.

Here's an example:

[image: graph example]

I can't give you more code because I'm really not comfortable with Javascript and this library :/

```
 chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline'
    },
    title: false,
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      minTickInterval: 3600*24*30*1000,
      minRange: 3600 * 24 * 30 * 1000,
      ordinal: false,
    yAxis: {
      title: false,
    },
    legend: false,
    credits: false,
    series: this.data
  };
```

Edit :

```
cheaperGoodsRented: Array(43)
0: {products_id: 17868008, date: "2020-07-05T00:00:00+02:00"}
1: {products_id: 17748578, date: "2020-07-04T00:00:00+02:00"}
2: {products_id: 17801501, date: "2020-07-30T00:00:00+02:00"}
3: {products_id: 17787239, date: "2020-07-29T00:00:00+02:00"}
4: {products_id: 14786582, date: "2020-07-28T00:00:00+02:00"}
5: {products_id: 17776231, date: "2020-07-28T00:00:00+02:00"}
6: {products_id: 17782348, date: "2020-07-28T00:00:00+02:00"}
7: {products_id: 17736554, date: "2020-07-22T00:00:00+02:00"}
8: {products_id: 17598542, date: "2016-07-16T00:00:00+02:00"}
9: {products_id: 11890379, date: "2016-07-03T00:00:00+02:00"}
10: {products_id: 15321772, date: "2020-06-18T00:00:00+02:00"}
11: {products_id: 14787637, date: "2020-06-05T00:00:00+02:00"}
12: {products_id: 14786913, date: "2020-06-20T00:00:00+02:00"}
13: {products_id: 14786508, date: "2020-06-01T00:00:00+02:00"}
14: {products_id: 14786733, date: "2020-06-31T00:00:00+02:00"}
15: {products_id: 14786690, date: "2020-06-24T00:00:00+01:00"}
16: {products_id: 14786884, date: "2020-06-19T00:00:00+01:00"}
17: {products_id: 14786587, date: "2020-06-18T00:00:00+01:00"}
18: {products_id: 16107731, date: "2020-06-11T00:00:00+01:00"}
19: {products_id: 15745972, date: "2020-06-23T00:00:00+01:00"}
20: {products_id: 15735719, date: "2020-06-21T00:00:00+01:00"}
21: {products_id: 15737339, date: "2020-06-21T00:00:00+01:00"}
22: {products_id: 15725593, date: "2020-06-20T00:00:00+01:00"}
23: {products_id: 14786586, date: "2020-06-16T00:00:00+01:00"}
24: {products_id: 15693410, date: "2020-06-13T00:00:00+01:00"}
25: {products_id: 14786615, date: "2020-06-09T00:00:00+01:00"}
26: {products_id: 15402278, date: "2020-06-19T00:00:00+01:00"}
27: {products_id: 15168169, date: "2020-06-22T00:00:00+02:00"}
28: {products_id: 15126845, date: "2020-06-13T00:00:00+02:00"}
29: {products_id: 14786891, date: "2020-06-06T00:00:00+02:00"}
30: {products_id: 15088131, date: "2020-06-03T00:00:00+02:00"}
31: {products_id: 15050034, date: "2020-06-25T00:00:00+02:00"}
32: {products_id: 6128961, date: "2020-06-16T00:00:00+02:00"}
33: {products_id: 14786660, date: "2020-05-12T00:00:00+02:00"}
34: {products_id: 14868614, date: "2020-05-28T00:00:00+02:00"}
35: {products_id: 14786881, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
36: {products_id: 14786893, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
37: {products_id: 14786911, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
38: {products_id: 14786920, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
39: {products_id: 14786834, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
40: {products_id: 14786871, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
41: {products_id: 14786876, date: "2020-05-07T00:00:00+02:00"}
42: {products_id: 6129048, date: "2020-05-14T00:00:00+02:00"}
```

Comment: Let's base on this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLvqnorm/ - as I understood the data API output is save as the variable data in the demo, but what and the `products_date_added` will be an x value for the chart, but what will be the y value?

Comment: If I say no nonsense, it would be the products_id.length that would be on the Y-axis?

Comment: No, it makes sense. Something like here is your requirement: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ox983zbn/?

Comment: The problem here is that the y-axis = products_id.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand what do you have in mind. Could you clarify the problem?

Comment: Looking at the picture I put in the post, don't you understand? I would like the number of products on the Y axis and the date on the X axis. The graph is made on the last 3 months. And I have to position one point per week.

Comment: So would you like to display the amount of the products per day on the yAxis? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5qv8egLk/

Comment: Not a week. If you want, I will receive about 150 products over the last 3 months. And I would like to get one point per week with the total number of products sold per week thanks to 'products_date_added'.

Comment: Could you share this data? I will try to work on it.

Comment: I edit my post for add a list of my datas

Comment: HCP please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tb72vazc/ is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thank u 
Its perfects !!!!